# Molar flux through membrane

Tags: concentration, diffusion

> Consider a liquid of pure $\ce{A}$ covered by a composite membrane through which
>   the vapor of $\ce{A}$ is diffusing. The membrane consists of two layers of thickness $l_1$ and $l_2$. The diffusion coefficient of $\ce{A}$ in the two layers are $D_{\ce{A},1}$ and $D_{\ce{A},2}$ respectively. On the lower side of the membrane, the concentration of $\ce{A}$ ($c^s_\ce{A})$ is controlled by the vapor pressure of $\ce{A}$. On the upper side the concentration of $\ce{A}$ is zero. The solubulity of $\ce{A}$ in the two membrane layers is the same.
>
> (a) Derive the expression for the flux $J_\ce{A}$ through the composite membrane
>
> [image]

The flux through a membrane is given by the equation:

$$J_\ce{A} = \frac{D_{AB}}{L}\left(c^{(m)}_{\ce{A},F} - c^{(m)}_{\ce{A},P}\right)$$

where, $c^{(m)}_{\ce{A},F}$ and $c^{(m)}_{\ce{A},P}$ are the concentrations at the edges inside the membrane.

So I would assume that $c^{(m)}_{\ce{A},F}$ = $c^s_\ce{A}$ and $c^{(m)}_{\ce{A},P}$ = $c_\ce{A}$

and because there are two membranes I would have to combine the diffusion coefficients as well as the lengths, which I do by addition to get the equation:

$$J_\ce{A} = \frac{D_{\ce{A},1} +D_{\ce{A},2}}{l_1 +l_2} (c^s_\ce{A} - c_\ce{A})$$

I am unsure if this is the correct way of deriving the expression for the flux when there are two membranes. Am I thinking correct?

**Edit**

I named the third concentration in the membrane $c_m$. Then I made two equations for the molar flux.

$$J_\ce{A} = \frac{D_{A,1}}{l_1}(c^s_A - c_m)$$

$$J_\ce{A} = \frac{D_{A,2}}{l_2}(c_m - c_A)$$

When rearranging and solving for $J_A$, I get:

$$J_\ce{A} = \frac{(c^s_A - c_A)}{\frac{l_1}{D_{A,1}}+\frac{l_2}{D_{A,2}}}$$

But that is the same answer as I got before

Comment: What you did is an exact equivalent of fractions addition in a "simple" way: $${1\over2}+{1\over3}={1+1\over2+3}={2\over5}.$$ Pity it ***never*** works like that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yeah, I thought that it couldn't be the correct way. How should it be derived?

Comment: Imagine a very thin layer of vapor _between_ the membranes (which is not really there, but hey, that's what imagination is for). Then you know the equation for the flux **to** this layer, and also **from** this layer, and the two are equal. Can you continue?

Comment: @IvanNeretin But when making two equations, one for the flux **to** the layer and one **from** the layer, how do I use the concentrations? Will I have $(c^s_\ce{A} - c_\ce{A})$ for both fluxes?

Comment: There will be a _third_ concentration, the one that exists between the membranes, initially unknown.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I am not sure if I understand how to solve this question. I tried to make two equations with a third concentration, but I get the same answer that I proposed in the beginning..

Comment: Now that's what I think is the correct answer. As for its relation with the one you've got before, I decisively insist that you review your opinions on the addition of fractions. Look again at the example from my first comment. What is ${1\over2}+{1\over3}$? Is it really ${2\over5}$? (Hint: it is **not**.)

Comment: @IvanNeretin Okay, thank you very much for all the help!